# EclipseLink JPA username/password Lookup deletes record on running the app

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, shiro

I am using apache shiro to authenticate a user and i want to simply print the username out to my console to check if my finder function is working properly, it seems as when i add a record to the user (using a sql statement and not eclipseLink, the record is deleted when the application is run ?)

Here is how i am trying to retrieve a single user by username:

```
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authcToken) throws AuthenticationException {
    UsernamePasswordToken token = (UsernamePasswordToken) authcToken;
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String tempUsername = token.getUsername();
    String password = "";
    Users user;

    // Null username is invalid
    if (tempUsername == null) {
        throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm.");
    }
    AuthenticationInfo info = null;
    // this will query and find the users by the specified username and then return us the single result
    user = getAuthorizedUser(Users.findUsersesByUsernameEquals(tempUsername));
    System.out.print(user.getUsername());
    System.out.println("yea the username = ");
    password = user.getPassword();
    info = buildAuthenticationInfo(tempUsername, password.toCharArray());
    return info;
}
/*Build the required authentication info; Replace with SaltAuthenticationInfo for salted passwords*/
protected AuthenticationInfo buildAuthenticationInfo(String username, char[] password) {
          return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, password, getName());
}

protected Users getAuthorizedUser(TypedQuery<Users> q){
    System.out.println("working authentication");

      return q.getSingleResult(); 
}
```

Is this because i am not using JPA to persist and add the user but rather writing a sql statement outside my application?

Comment: No idea what your question is.  Perhaps explain what happens better and include the log on finest.

Comment: I ended up doing this and found things working properly but a property was set that kept dropping tables and creating them on each run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled this property `<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>`

This was deleting my test records and solved my problem.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you can, make sure you mark your answer as "Accepted" so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~